# Lucene nightly build javadoc?

Tags: java, lucene

Can I read the javadoc for Lucene nightly build 4.0 ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Er.

google for "lucene nightly build javadoc".

http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/api/index.html

JA